# Is it possible to create a jdbc connection without a password (using postgresql 'trust')?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using jdbc to connect to a postgresql database in a java application (actually the app is written in Groovy).  I have postgresql set up to use the 'trust' authentication method.  Is it possible to open a jdbc connection without specifying a password?  When I try to use the normal constructor with a blank password, it fails with

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

Even though, from the command line, this works fine

```
psql -U myuser mydatabase
Welcome to psql 8.3.5, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
      \h for help with SQL commands
      \? for help with psql commands
      \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
      \q to quit
```

Comment: First check the authentication with psql but from the same machine from which you're trying to connect with JDBC - I have the feeling the "trust" authentication is enabled only for local connections and you're trying to connect with JDBC from another machine.

Comment: @Milen "trust" authentication (i.e., no password) can be used also for  ip connections

Comment: @leonbloy - please re-read what I've written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Note that Postres JDBC driver always uses IP sockets (`host` in `pg_hba.conf`), even if database is on the local machine, then `psql` can use local sockets (`local` in `pg_hba.conf`). So, if `psql` works with `trust` authentication and JDBC doesn't, you probably should configure `trust` authentication for IP sockets, [see documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So can I use the normal jdbc constructor and just pass in a blank password?

Comment: I added a new line like: host DATABASE USERNAME 127.0.0.1/32 trust, but i had to remove this line above: host all  all 127.0.0.1/32 md5

Answer (score 4):

Already answered but:

When you connect using the `psql` client program, and don't specify a host (`-h`), the default is to use a **local socket** (at least in Linux). In JDBC, instead, you will use a **TCP/IP** socket. Then, to check your connection problem you should invoke psql with the same settings you are using in JDBC, host included.

For example

```
 psql -U myuser -h 127.0.0.1 mydatabase    # uses TCP/IP
```

Which is not the same as

```
 psql -U myuser mydatabase      # uses local socket (non TCP/IP)
```

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish at least including version 3.1 has an [issue with specifying empty JDBC passwords](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12188).